# extjs 6.53 increase remote request timeout globally

Tags: ajax, extjs6.5

I have put the following inside Application.js:

```
Ext.Ajax.setTimeout(300000);
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Server, { timeout: Ext.Ajax.getTimeout() });
```

My store still timeouts after 30s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to override it for both ajax/proxy, however you override the one for ajax via the `Connection`. In your code, for the proxy you've overridden the timeout to be a function reference.

```
Ext.define(null, {
  override: 'Ext.data.Connection',
  timeout: 1
});

Ext.define(null, {
  override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
  config: {
    timeout: 1
  }
});
```